# Insert an article and fields with db_insert function or SQL

Tags: 7, database

I want to add an article to the db using db insert along with its field like tags and image.

A sample code i tried(below) is adding data to the db but I can't find any entry in the

```
db_insert('node')
  ->fields(array(
    'title' => "hello world",
    'created' => REQUEST_TIME,
    // 'body' => 'you did it!',
    'uid' => 1,
    'vid' => 5,
    'type'=>'article',

  ))
   ->execute();
```

If not this, can it be done using a normal sql query?

**Why I want to do this way instead of `nodesave`?**

- I don't want any hooks working on this process.
- This is a temperory fast solution I want for a project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to save a node without invoking any hook, then use the same code [node_save()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_save/7) uses, excluding the part invoking hooks.

```
  $transaction = db_transaction();

  try {
    if (!empty($node->nid) && !isset($node->original)) {
      $node->original = entity_load_unchanged('node', $node->nid);
    }

    field_attach_presave('node', $node);
    global $user;

    if (!isset($node->is_new)) {
      $node->is_new = empty($node->nid);
    }

    if (empty($node->created)) {
      $node->created = REQUEST_TIME;
    }
    $node->changed = REQUEST_TIME;
    $node->timestamp = REQUEST_TIME;
    $update_node = TRUE;

    if ($node->is_new || !empty($node->revision)) {
      if (!isset($node->log)) {
        $node->log = '';
      }
    }
    elseif (!isset($node->log) || $node->log === '') {
      unset($node->log);
    }

    if (!$node->is_new && !empty($node->revision) && $node->vid) {
      $node->old_vid = $node->vid;
      unset($node->vid);
    }

    if ($node->is_new) {
      drupal_write_record('node', $node);
      _node_save_revision($node, $user->uid);
      $op = 'insert';
    }
    else {
      drupal_write_record('node', $node, 'nid');
      if (!empty($node->revision)) {
        _node_save_revision($node, $user->uid);
      }
      else {
        _node_save_revision($node, $user->uid, 'vid');
        $update_node = FALSE;
      }
      $op = 'update';
    }
    if ($update_node) {
      db_update('node')->fields(array('vid' => $node->vid))->condition('nid', $node->nid)->execute();
    }

    // Call the node specific callback (if any). This can be
    // node_invoke($node, 'insert') or
    // node_invoke($node, 'update').
    node_invoke($node, $op);

    // Save fields.
    $function = "field_attach_$op";
    $function('node', $node);

    $delete = $op == 'update';
    node_access_acquire_grants($node, $delete);

    unset($node->is_new);
    unset($node->original);
    entity_get_controller('node')->resetCache(array($node->nid));

    db_ignore_slave();
  }
  catch (Exception $e) {
    $transaction->rollback();
    watchdog_exception('node', $e);
    throw $e;
  }
```

I didn't remove the call to [node_invoke()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_invoke/7), since that calls the hooks implemented by the module implementing the content type, and those hooks are necessary for the content type to work correctly.
I also left the call to `db_transaction()` because, in the case one of the operations fails, all the operations are rolled back, and the database is left in a consistent state, which means (for example) that every table will refer to the same node version ID.

Comment: That really helped.

Comment: This made bulk creation of nodes way faster, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Although strongly recommended to use `node_save` instead (e.g via [Batch API](https://drupal.org/node/180528) ), if you're going to manually add nodes that way you'll need to insert into the `node_revision` table as well.

Comment: He might also want to update the *field_<field_name>* and the instance tables of the fields which are a part of the node being added.

Comment: Totally agree with @AjitS